# Delete all dataframe rows that are associated with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have this dataframe:

```
df = {'ID' : [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
     'x':[76.551, 79.529, 78.336,77, 76.02, 79.23, 77.733, 79.249,  76.077],
     'y': [151.933, 152.945, 153.970, 119.369, 120.615, 118.935, 119.115, 152.004, 153.027],
    'position': ['start', 'end', 'start', 'NA', 'NA','NA','end', 'start', 'end']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
   ID       x        y position
0   1  76.551  151.933    start
1   1  79.529  152.945      end
2   1  78.336  153.970    start
3   1  77.000  119.369       NA
4   1  76.020  120.615       NA
5   1  79.230  118.935       NA
6   1  77.733  119.115      end
7   2  79.249  152.004    start
8   2  76.077  153.027      end
```

I want to delete all the rows that are associated with an end point between certain values. I can specify the end points that I want to remove with:

```
df[(df['position'] == 'end') & (df['x'] > 75) & (df['x'] < 78)]
```

but how do I remove all the rows associated with that condition?

Output would look like:

```
   ID       x        y position
0   1  76.551  151.933    start
1   1  79.529  152.945      end
```

EDIT: the context is that these are trajectories from different animals (with particular ID), if the animal's end coordinate lies between particular x-axis values, i want to remove that animal's whole trajectory from the model.

Comment: What you want does not match your requirement. You have that `'position'` cannot be `'end'` but then in your output you have an example where it does. You also want to have `x` not in the range 75-80 but both your final values have that.

Comment: oh, what i mean is "if 'position' = 'end' & 'x' >75  & 'x' <78" remove and delete all the values that are within that start-end group. my mistake for the example, i'll fix it to fit within the correct range (i just took arbitrary ones for the example)

Comment: kas: looks like your list the two rows you want to **drop** from the output, not the desired output. Please edit your question. Anyway, equivalently, you could just invert the condition, and select rows where `(df['position'] != 'end') | (df['x'] <= 75) | (df['x'] >= 78)`

Comment: Also, Python allows comparison chaining, so you can directly say `75 < df['x'] < 78`

Comment: i think my example should be correct. i have 3 animal trajectories (2 are by the same animal). animal end points at index 6 and 8 lie between 75-78, therefore, i want to remove their whole path from the data. sorry, if this was not clear

Comment: @smci Note that comparison chaining doesn't work with `pandas.Series`. `75 < df['x'] < 78` is translated into `75 < df['x']  and  df['x'] < 78` not `(75 < df['x']) & (df['x'] < 78)`. Since both  comparisons  produce boolean Series and the truthiness of a Series is ambiguous, an error is raised. You can use the `Series.between` method tho.

Comment: @Rodalm: thanks for pointing that out. But `df.query('position=="end" & 75 < x < 78')` does work.

Comment: @smci True, that is a clean way also. But in that case the substring `'75 < x < 78'` is simply parsed and interpreted as `(df[‘x’] > 75) & (df[‘x’] < 78)` or something similar.

Comment: @Rodalm: interesting. There are several differences in syntax of boolean and comparison expressions between base Python, pandas and df.query(). Worthy of their own question. This stuff constantly trips up me and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean mask:

```
m = (df['position'] == 'end') & (df['x'] > 75) & (df['x'] < 78)
out = df[~m.groupby(df['position'].eq('start').cumsum()).transform('max')]
print(out)

# Output
   ID       x        y position
0   1  76.551  151.933    start
1   1  79.529  152.945      end
```

I already used in your previous question `df['position'].eq('start').cumsum()` to create virtual groups to identify the different trajectories.

Comment: ahh yes, i referred to that previously but didn't know where to incorporate it. i'm still not super comfortable with the python syntax and need to learn more about the virtual grouping documentation. thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using [`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
rows_to_remove = df[(df['position'] == 'end') & (df['x'] > 75) & (df['x'] < 78)].index.values
df = df.drop(rows_to_remove)
```

Comment: thanks, do you know how to remove all the other values that are associated with those 'end' position i want to remove? essentially these are trajectory data and if the end point lies between a particular coordinate, i want to completely remove that whole trajectory (so all the values from start to end of that trajectory, if the end coord is between the specified coordinate)